# SeqWrapper is not a valid external type for schema of array<string>

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create a dataframe out of a `Seq[Row]`. Each row has data like below

```
val id = 12
val name = John
val role_ids = [156fuioh, 979auihf, 098hfhjd]

Row(id, name, role_ids)
```

I would like to convert above seq of rows into a `DataFrame`. So I created below schema

```
val schema = StructType( Array(
        StructField("id", StringType,true),
        StructField("name", StringType,true),
        StructField("role_ids", ArrayType(StringType, true),true),
      ))
```

And then trying to create a `DataFrame` using below statement

```
val someDF = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(memberRows), StructType(schema))

someDf.show(false)
```

And I'm getting below error

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$SeqWrapper is not a valid external type for schema of array<string>
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.MapObjects_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.writeFields_0_1$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:288)
```

Comment: membersRows role_ids fiel is a String, not an array. Add the code that creates this Seq[Row]

Comment: I have updated the question a bit. there was a typo in my code and the error I was getting was different.

Comment: @EmilianoMartinez: I was able to solve it by converting the role_ids to array by using role_ids.toArray. Thanks for your help

Comment: @axn7975 please add that as an answer. It helped me.